# asp.net master page and viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have some values that are set on a master page and that I want to save across a postback. I then want these variable to be available to pages using that master page during their load events.

Easy enough to create properties on the master page. So my first try to was to say that during the master page's load event, if not ispostback then generate the values and save them to the viewstate, else read them from the viewstate.

Except ... apparently the regular page load event happens BEFORE the master page load event, so the data wasn't there yet when I tried to read it.

Second try: have the master page set or retrieve these values during the Init event. No luck. Appears that the view state is not populated by Init time.

As far as I can tell, there's no event on a master page that happens after view state is populated but before the main page's Load event.

I suppose each page could have an InitComplete or PreLoad that calls a function to populate these fields, but that seems really clumsy. The call would have to be in every page. And it would have to be in every page even if that page never used this data, because the master page uses the data for its own purposes.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe view state is not the right place to save the data? I could store the data in Session variables, but then on not-postback the data in them would be left over from the last call. I guess I could make sure to clear the obsolete data, but that seems really clumsy.

I'm writing in VB but I wouldn't think that would make a difference here.

Comment: Hm... If you stored this data in a public variable or property on the Master Page, you might be able to access it on the child pages by adding a `@MasterType` directive, which allows you to do something like `MyCompany.Text = Master.CompanyName`. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx). Though, I'm not sure where this would fall into the master-child pageload cycle, nor does this resolve your issue of having to modify every child page.

Comment: @santi Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. The problem isn't getting to the master page variable from the child page, it's getting that master page variable set before the child's Load event.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I should clarify: Yes, I expect every child page to have to say, foobar=master.foobar or whatever it needs to do with the value from the master page. Each child page needs its own code to do that. The catch is having master.foobar populated before the child's Load event happens. I'd prefer the child to not have to do anything to make the population happen, because the master page also needs this data, and I don't want the master dependent on the child triggering the population at the right time. Children should depend on their parents, not parents on their children.

Comment: Well, in regards to your `Session` idea, evidently the child `Page_Load` happens *before* the Master's. Why not store a `Session` on the the event that is causing your MasterPage to post-back, use it in the child's `Page_Load`, and then simply clear that session value on the MasterPage's `Page_Load`? That session would only exist from the duration of the triggering event, to the following Page_Load, meaning it clears out every time the Master post's back, however it would exist on "not postback" of your child page.

Comment: I feel you should create a base page to do this. Master page is just a user control and is in the page's control collection. In this sense, master page is not the parent of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could override [LoadViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.loadviewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the master page in the following manner:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
     base.LoadViewState(savedState);

     // use the loaded values, if any, here
}
```

`LoadViewState` is called before Load and in fact even before `PreLoad` of the page, so that seems to fit what you are looking for.